# How to name the tag for the particles "は", "へ", and "を"?

Tags: discussion, tags

We are evolving more and more particle-specific tags such as [particle-ni](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-ni) and [particle-to](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-to) but what to do with these three oddball particles?

- Follow place in the kana tables: ha, he, wo
- Follow pronunciation: wa, e, o
- If we go with pronunciation should we still go with "wo" for the object particle?

Comment: yay, glad to see this idea taking off :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that since people will be thinking of the particles themselves when tagging that the pronunciation should be used wa, e should be used.  However, を, is actually pronounced "wo" so that should be used.  having "particle-o" might not very clear as to which particle it is while "particle-wo" is pretty clear (though this could just be because i'm used to thinking of を as "wo".

Comment: Some (I guess many, but I am not sure) Japanese speakers pronounce お and を in the same way.  I do not know whether most foreign speakers of Japanese pronounce お and を differently or not.

Comment: "wo" is non-standard. Writing so lacks consistency. We should use "o".

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I find your comment interesting as my Japanese teachers and my wife scold me when I pronounce them the same.  
  
Though you may be correct that it is so subtle that most foreign speakers of Japanese might not pronounce it.

Comment: For me, forcing the pronunciation “wo” for particle を sounds just as ridiculous as forcing the pronunciation “he” for particle へ.  But I have heard that some dialects use the pronunciation “wo.”

Answer (score 2):

I would say to go with "wa", "e", and "wo" as proposed by Mark.

I think any (sane :)) naming scheme is fine as long as we apply tag synonyms to ensure that the questions are categorized properly and consistently.